# Why does directional stability decrease at supersonic speeds?

Tags: stability, supersonic, yaw, transonic

As an aircraft accelerates through the transonic region from full subsonic to to full supersonic flow its directional or yaw stability decreases. What causes this reduction?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a combination of several effects:

1. Aeroelasticity: With the higher forces at high speed, the structure deforms such that the effective flow angle at the tail surface is reduced.
2. The supersonic lift curve slope of the tail surface decreases with Mach while that of the fuselage stays roughly constant, so with higher Mach the tail contribution to stability shrinks while the destabilizing contribution of the fuselage stays the same.
3. Tail location: At supersonic speed the density of air on the upper fuselage is reduced while that on the bottom is increased. Since the vertical sits on top of the fuselage, it flies in rarefied air. Ventral fins, on the other hand, become more effective.

The supersonic lift curve slope is approximately $$c_{L\alpha}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{Ma^2-1}}\cdot\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{2\cdot AR\cdot\sqrt{Ma^2-1}}\right)$$
Note that the second term is for the influence of the triangular surface on the tip where the pressure difference is reduced. Nevertheless, it shows that lift curve slope of the vertical decreases with increasing Mach number.

For the fuselage, the lift curve slope is that of a slender body:$$c_{L\alpha}=\pi\cdot\frac{AR}{2}$$
Note that this equation is independent of Mach, so the destabilizing fuselage contribution stays constant over Mach.

For the beneficial influence of ventral fins see the diagram below which has been published by Lockheed in The F-104 Strafighter Test Pilot's Notebook by Glenn L. Reaves ([source](http://www.916-starfighter.de/SnakeReaves_TestPilotNotebookF-104.PDF)):

[image: F-104 ventral fin contribution to directional stability]

Comment: Thank you. That seems to clear it up nicely.

Comment: *while the destabilizing contribution of the fuselage stays the same* why *stays the same*? Doesn't the center of pressure move forward?

Comment: @Abdullah: The fuselage behaves like a slender body, its center of pressure is already near the tip and the forces on it don't change that much with Mach number.

Comment: Are you saying sub vs supersonic or supersonic vs more supersonic? I mean, at subsonic speeds, we have viscosity effects that just don't work that much at Mach>1

Comment: I guess the sensitivity to aeroelasticity must vary greatly depending on the relative locations of engine/s and tail fin/s. For example if the tail were rigidly mounted above a single engine, the thrust line would tend to move with it.

Comment: @GuyInchbald: Much of supersonic thrust is created in the intake. Yes, fuselage bending will also bend nozzle thrust, but on the fin you need to add the effect of torsion. Using thin supersonic airfoils will give it relatively little torsional stiffness. In total, the destabilizing effect of nozzle thrust adds to the loss of directional stability suffered by the elastic tail, but not much.

Comment: Yes indeed. It will still be sensitive to mechanical layout, though.

Comment: "At supersonic speed the density of air on the upper fuselage is reduced while that on the bottom is increased." Why is that?

Comment: @JZYL Because of compressibility and the desire to fly at an angle of attack in order to create enough lift. Air on top is thinner than air on the bottom of the wings and fuselage. And this becomes worse with higher Mach numbers. Remember that at subsonic speed it's the pressure that changes most while at supersonic speed the density changes become dominant.

Answer (score 4):

Because:

[image]

Here you see a fuselage viewed from above. The horizontal line at the right end of the ellipse is the tailfin. On top is a subsonic plane, and at the bottom is a supersonic one. 
The thin lines are pressure, the thick ones are forces, and the arrows show flow direction and magnitude.

As you can see, at subsonic speeds suction is more dominant, therefore, the tail, where more suction occurs, produces more sideforce, stabilising the plane.

**EDIT:** However, this effect is not that significant.

The below diagram shows the tailcone of the same plane.

[image]

As you can see, the same thing happens to the tailfin. But the effect of this center-of-pressure movement can't be *that* significant. However, the back half of the stabilizer becomes less effective at supersonic speed due to being in the low pressure "wake" of whatever is ahead, (the fuselage, as Peter said, or even the front section of the fin itself) as wakes are more defined at these high speeds.

The X-15 had a wedge-shaped tail fin [because of this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/71292/45534)

Comment: So if side pressure increases so much at the nose, why does it not also increase in similar proportion at the tail fin?

Comment: Let me add another diagram.

Comment: @GuyInchbald *why does it not also increase in similar proportion at the tail fin?* You're missing one point. The destabilizing effect of pressure on the nose**cone** increases while the stabilizing effect of pressure on the tail**cone** decreases.

Comment: Of course I am missing something, that is why I am asking! Thank you anyway, but I find Peter's analysis to be the more convincing.

Comment: @GuyInchbald That's OK, even I upvoted him. I was just clarifying my answer because you misinterpreted it.

Comment: Did I? I rather think you must have misinterpreted me to conclude that I was interpreting anything. But you and I have been here before, we should let it pass.